# mdframed with page break

Tags: mdframed

I am using `mdframed` in my document. However, when a page break happens, for example when LaTeX decides to insert one before a paragraph starts, `mdframed` does not complete the frame to cover the whole page, instead the frame  surrounds the text only which leaves some empty space at the bottom of the page. Is there a way to get the frame extended to the end of the page? Or is there an alternative to `mdframed` that does what I want?

The below MWE illustrates the problem by inserting `\vskip` manually. However, in my real case I do not know where the page break will be.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
  \lipsum[1]
\begin{mdframed}[everyline=true]
%\begin{tcolorbox}[sharp corners,breakable,
% height fill,colback=white,colframe=black]    % Almost same output
  \lipsum[2-3]
  \vskip 3cm
  \lipsum[4-5]
\end{mdframed}
%end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

Current output on left, desired on right (Notice the borders on the first page)

[image: Current output] [image: Desired output]

Comment: use tcolorbox instead of mdframed. It is much better and much more reliable in such cases.

Comment: Could you please edit your question to add a sketch of the desired output?

Comment: I added the current/desired output. @Ulrike I tried tcolorbox and it seems to have the same output (even when using `height fill`)